# How to convert from assembly into readable code in a higher level language?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I want to understand an algorithm that was written in assembler.
The code looks like this

```
 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP]   - Put Value, entered into EAX
 Mov ECX, EAX                 - Copy value from EAX to ECX
 AND EAX,0xBBD13D22           - add ???
 NOT ECX                      - ???
 NOT EAX                      - ???
 AND ECX,EAX                  - ???
 IMUL ECX,ECX,0x74ACD16       - multiply ECX with &H74ACD16 and put result to ECX - but it's DWORD ???????
 ROL ECX,0x10                 - Rotate Left, but ????
 IMUL ECX,ECX,0xBBB38D0       - result ???
```

Could please anybody explain to me, how this code would look like in, let's say Visual Basic.

It's a mathematics operation, but I just know very little of assembler.

Could please anybody help me with that?

Sorry for my bad English, but still learning.

Comment: how these instructions work would be explained clearly in Intel's manual. For example [NOT](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/NOT.html), [ROL](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RCL:RCR:ROL:ROR.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit difficult to see how the higher-level programming language conversion will help you, because for example the C++ variant looks almost the same (for seasoned asm programmer, that is):

```
int32_t someCalculation(int32_t input_value) {
    int32_t ecxL4 = ~input_value;                   // ecx after "NOT ecx" (line 4)
    int32_t eaxL5 = ~(input_value & 0xBBD13D22);    // eax after "NOT eax" (line 5)
    int32_t ecxL6 = ecxL4 & eaxL5;
    int32_t ecxL7 = ecxL6 * 0x74ACD16;              // IMUL ECX,ECX,0x74ACD16
    int32_t ecxL8 = (ecxL7<<16) | ((ecxL7>>16)&0xFFFF); // ROL ecx,0x10
    return ecxL8 * 0xBBB38D0;                       // IMUL ECX,ECX,0xBBB38D0
}
```

which gets compiled with gcc 8.2 for 32 bit target as:

```
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
    not     eax
    imul    eax, eax, 122342678
    rol     eax, 16
    imul    eax, eax, 196819152
    ret
```

As you can see, the compiler correctly understands the initial two `and`s will in the end produce the value (*) equal to the `not <input_value>`, so the first original 6 lines are optimized into two, then the rest is same as original code (except using register `eax` instead of `ecx` for calculation).

*) why same value? Because the first `AND EAX,0xBBD13D22` will keep only some bits set from the input value, and those will become "0" after `not`, so those could possibly affect `ecx` value after `and ecx,eax`. But the bits which will be zeroed by that `and` were set to ones in `ecx` too (it was copy of input value), and after `not ecx` they have become zeroes too, so essentially that part with `eax` doesn't do anything to the `not <input_value>` calculation.

IMO you need more like do some exercises with those math functions, watching also binary representation of values, and figuring out how those operations are implemented on bit level, the C++ source is basically identical to the original assembly, so I don't see how this will help you.

I can't produce Visual Basic variant, because I don't know that ... erhm... programming language? ... but it will very likely end either similar to C++ (i.e. basically the same as assembly), or you will run into some operation being not available directly with 32 bit integers, then you will have to hack-in those 32 bit truncations/ranges by doing that bit-level math yourself.

---

edit: actually the `ROL` is somewhat tricky in C++, because there's no direct operation for that one, only shifts are available in the C++, so I did automatically write the correct bit manipulation to get the same result as `ROL` will produce (shifting one half of value by 16 to left and use that as upper 16b part of result and shifting upper half into down 16b and combine the result by OR-ing it). I didn't even think about it so much, so I didn't realize it's actually that thing I'm talking about in the paragraph above, when the language doesn't support some operation directly. Also as you can see, the idiom is recognized by the compiler, and instead of compiling it as two shifts, one `and` and one `or`, it will use `rol` directly.